# Inductive Proof Recursive Definition

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

Using this recursive Definition:

> $$a_{n} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
> 4 & n=1\\ 
> a_{n-1}+4n-5 & n \geq 2
> \end{matrix}\right.$$

I somehow have to prove using induction

> $$a_{n} = 2n^{2} - 3n + 5, n\geq 1$$

Comment: have you learn anything about induction today?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, let's solve this one using generating functions.

Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$. Write the recurrence as:
$$
a_{n + 1} = a_n + 4 n - 1
$$
It is nicer starting with index 0, so use the recurrence "backwards" to get $a_0 = 5$.

Multiply the recurrence by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$, and recognize:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n &= \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} z^n           &= \frac{1}{1 - z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} n z^n         
  &= z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1}{1 - z} \\
  &= \frac{z}{(1 - z)^2}
\end{align}
to get:
$$
\frac{A(z) - 5}{z} = A(z) + \frac{4 z}{(1 - z)^2} - \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
Solve for $A(z)$, and express as partial fractions:
$$
A(z) = \frac{5 - 11 z + 10 z^2}{1 - 3 z + 3 z^2 - z^3}
     = \frac{4}{(1 - z)^3} - \frac{9}{(1 - z)^2} + \frac{10}{1 - z}
$$
By the (extended) binomial theorem for $r \in \mathbb{N}$ it is:
$$
(1 - z)^{-r}
  = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-r}{k} (-1)^k z^k
  = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + r - 1}{r - 1} z^k
$$
so that:
$$
A(z)
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} 
      \left( 4 \binom{n + 2}{2} - 9 \binom{n + 1}{1} + 10 \right) z^n
$$
and thus:
$$
a_n = 4 \binom{n + 2}{2} - 9 \binom{n + 1}{1} + 10
    = \frac{4 (n + 2) (n + 1)}{2} - \frac{9 (n + 1)}{1} + 10
    = 2 n^2 - 3 n + 5
$$